# not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) when loop through dict

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
zip_values = [{'Spain': '43004'}, {'Spain': '43830'}, {'Spain': '46003'}, {'Spain': '50006'}, {'Portugal': ''}, {'Portugal': '1000-155'}, {'Portugal': '1000-226'}, {'Portugal': '1050-175'}, {'Portugal': '1050-190'}, {'Portugal': '1070-041'}, {'Portugal': '1150-101'}, {'Portugal': '1150-260'}, {'Portugal': '1200-114'}, {'Portugal': '1250-192'}, {'Portugal': '1300-243'}, {'Portugal': '1300-610'}, {'Portugal': '1350-100'}, {'Portugal': '1400-140'}, {'Portugal': '1400-212'}, {'Portugal': '1400-352'}, {'Portugal': '1495-057'}, {'Portugal': '1495-135'}, {'Portugal': '1500-073'}, {'Portugal': '1500-151'}, {'Portugal': '1500-506'}, {'Portugal': '1600-161'}, {'Portugal': '1600-864'}, {'Portugal': '1700-093'}, {'Portugal': '1700-163'}, {'Portugal': '1700-239'}, {'Portugal': '1750-249'}, {'Portugal': '1750-429'}, {'Portugal': '1800-297'}, {'Portugal': '1950-130'}, {'Portugal': '1990-179'}]
```

but much larger. I want to loop over it, I try like this

```
for key, value in zip_values:
    if key == "France" | key == "Germany" | key == "Spain":
        current_zip = check_if_zipcodes_correct(value, 1000, 99999, 5)
```

check_if_zipcodes_correct is some function that I want to use for zipcodes, but it is not important, I get an error when run the script:
**ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)**

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to iterate over a list of dictionaries, `for key, value in zip_values` would try to map the `key` and `value` to a dictionary object(e.g. - `{'Spain': '43004'}`) which is not supported. Had it been a `list`/`tuple`(e.g. `[ Spain', '43004']` it would have worked.

Try something like this -

```
for d in zip_values:
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key in ("France", "Germany", "Spain"):
            current_zip = check_if_zipcodes_correct(value, 1000, 99999, 5)
```

Additionally, `if key == "France" | key == "Germany" | key == "Spain"` can be simplified to `if key in ("France", "Germany", "Spain")`

Answer (score 1):

Every item in `zip_values` is a single 'dict` object , you can't unpack it to two items. You need to iterate over the list and take the first key value pair from each dictionary

```
for d in zip_values:
    key, value = next(iter(d.items()))
    # or
    key, value = list(d.items())[0]
```

In addition you can't use `|` like this, you need to warppe it with brackets

```
if (key == "France") | (key == "Germany") | (key == "Spain")
```

use logical condition

```
if key == "France" or key == "Germany" or key == "Spain":
```

or use `in` on a list

```
if key in ["France", "Germany", "Spain"]
```